# COALESCE(FIELD, "DEFAULT VALUE") not working for postgresql + rails

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(p.*), concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as fullname, concat('@',u.username) as username, cover.file_path, cover.file_type, avatar.avatar_path 
       FROM products p
       JOIN stores s ON s.id = p.store_id
       JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fh.product_id AS cp_id, 
       coalesce(fh.file_path, 'default image path') AS file_path,
       fh.file_type AS file_type FROM file_handlers fh WHERE is_cover = true) cover ON p.id = cover.cp_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fh.id AS av_id, fh.file_path AS avatar_path FROM file_handlers fh WHERE is_cover = false) avatar ON u.avatar_id = avatar.av_id"
```

Above is my raw sql query for my postgresql database. My problem is I want to display default file_path if it is null in the database. I tried three methods for this:

```
1. COALESCE(fh.file_path, 'default image') AS file_path,
2. COALESCE(NULLIF(fh.file_path, ''), 'default image') AS file_path,
3. CASE WHEN fh.file_path IS NULL THEN 'default image' ELSE fh.file_path END AS file_path,
```

No Luck!, none of them works for me, and I don't know why. What am I missing here?

[NOTE: please see [this screenshot](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4i07b/bcw6)]

Comment: your first COALESCE example is correct, have you tried executing the query on the database directly? What does it return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will give it a try in database directly, and let you know..

Comment: It is returning null value for file_path in postgres database also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain your problem is due to the left join, rather than the coalesce. If the left join yields no row, `cover.file_path` ends up null regardless of the coalesce or not.

Try moving the coalesce statement to a more appropriate location:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(p.*), concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as fullname, concat('@',u.username) as username, coalesce(cover.file_path, 'default image path'), cover.file_type, avatar.avatar_path 
FROM products p
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. now in postgres database it is working fine but still I am not getting expected result in view page.

Comment: CASE WHEN fh.file_path IS NULL THEN 'default image' ELSE fh.file_path END AS file_path.. ... works for me instead of COALESCE().... by the way thanks a lot to oll for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.*), concat(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as fullname, 
CASE 
  WHEN 
    cover.file_path IS NULL AND cover.file_type='image' 
  THEN 
    'DEFAULT IMAGE PATH' 
  WHEN
    cover.file_path IS NULL AND cover.file_type='audio' 
  THEN 
    'DEFAULT AUDIO PATH' 
  WHEN
    cover.file_path IS NULL AND cover.file_type='video' 
  THEN 
    'DEFAULT VIDEO PATH'
  ELSE 
    cover.file_path 
END,     
CASE 
  WHEN avatar.avatar_path IS NULL 
  THEN 'avatar.png' 
  ELSE avatar.avatar_path 
END
FROM products p
JOIN stores s ON s.id = p.store_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fh.product_id AS cp_id, fh.file_path AS file_path, fh.file_type AS  file_type FROM file_handlers fh WHERE is_cover = true) cover ON p.id = cover.cp_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fh.id AS av_id, fh.file_path AS avatar_path FROM file_handlers fh WHERE is_cover = false) avatar ON u.avatar_id = avatar.av_id
```

works for me...yah!